# jQuery. Записать значение тега в массив

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, массивы

Итак, имеется плагин ion-sound. Ему передается параметр в виде массива с названиями аудиозаписей, примерно так:

```js
ion.sound({
      sounds: [
          {name: "Добрый день"},
          {name: "Кхм кхм"},
          {name: "Россия"}
      ],
      path: "audio/",
      preload: false,
      volume: 1.0
});
$('.button--audio').on('click', function() {
   var valueButton = $(this).text();
   ion.sound.play(valueButton);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/static/js/ion-sound/ion.sound.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card"><button class="button button--audio">Добрый день</button></div>
   <div class="card"><button class="button button--audio">Кхм кхм</button></div>
   <div class="card"><button class="button button--audio">Россия</button></div>
```

В HTML при нажатии на кнопку происходит воспроизведение аудио.
Суть в том, что, если нужно добавить новую кнопку, то надо создавать ее не только в HTML, но и записывать новый элемент в массив.
Можно ли сделать, чтобы в JavaScript автоматически происходила запись значений новых элементов при добавлении кнопок в разметку?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

DOMNodeInserted событие добавления элемента, по нему вешай обработчики